# Portfolio Theory: Currency Risk

Tags: modern-portfolio-theory

It seems to me that Currency Risk can be diversified away and hence one should not get paid for taking it.  Do you agree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, FX generally does not command a risk premium (expected return = 0, but volatility is not 0), and you can improve the Sharpe ratios of global equity/bond portfolios just by hedging away FX risk. See this excellent AQR paper: [Risk Without Reward: The Case for Strategic FX Hedging](https://www.aqr.com/library/aqr-publications/risk-without-reward-the-case-for-strategic-fx-hedging).